# How to add item into List<Integer> when checked checkBox on Android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

In my application i have 3 `checkBoxs`. And i want when **checked** each of this `checkbox`s **add** value into `List<integer>` and when **unchecked** it, **remove** this value from `List<Integer>`.
**For example :** I have 3 `ceckbox`s .
**Android** - **Ios** - **Windows** .
I want when **Android** is checked add number **2** into `List`.
 
when **Ios** is checked add number **4** into `List`.
 
when **Windows** is checked add number **8** into `List`.
 
And when **uncheck** each of this `checkbox`s, **remove** this number from `List`.

I write below codes, but not show me true result!

```
btnTesterSignUp.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (signUp_pcCheck.isChecked()) {
            userDevicesList.add(0, 2);
        } else {
            if (userDevicesList.size() > 0)
                try {
                    userDevicesList.remove(0);
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
        }

        if (signUp_mobileCheck.isChecked()) {
            userDevicesList.add(1, 4);
        } else {
            if (userDevicesList.size() > 0)
                try {
                    userDevicesList.remove(1);
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
        }

        if (signUp_tabletCheck.isChecked()) {
            userDevicesList.add(2, 8);
        } else {
            if (userDevicesList.size() > 0)
                try {
                    userDevicesList.remove(2);
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
        }

        Log.e("userDevicesLog", userDevicesList.toString());

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```java
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        CheckBox ios = ...
        CheckBox android = ...
        ios.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            if (isChecked)
                list.add(2);
            else if (list.contains(2))
                list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
        });
        android.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            if (isChecked)
                list.add(4);
            else if (list.contains(4))
                list.remove(Integer.valueOf(4));
        });
```

Comment: Use english my friend.
I changed code.
You can remove from an Array list by using index or an object.
here cause we have an Integer array you should Use Integer.valueOf to pass and Integer object to remove not index.